# What is the approach to solve simple constrained optimization when first order condition $\nabla f = 0$ yields solution outside of domain

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I wish to solve the problem

min $ f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 - x_1 + x_2 + x_1x_2$

subj $x_1\ge 0, x_2 \ge 0$

We find $\nabla f = [2x_1 - 1 + x_2, 1+x_1] = 0$ yields $x_1 = -1, x_2 = 3$ which is outside the domain

What are some approaches to proceed from here to find the minimum which is $x_1 = 1/2, x_2 = 0$

Comment: This is not convex so I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you've determined that the derivative doesn't help, now you have to check the boundaries of the domain, that is when $x_1 = 0$ or when $x_2 = 0$, the first yields
$$f(0 , x_2) = x_2$$
the minimum value of this on the domain $x_2 \geq 0$ is $x_2 = 0$. The second condition gets us
$$f(x_1, 0) = x_1^2 - x_1$$
Differentiating that yields
$$f'(x_1, 0) = 2x_1 - 1$$
Which shows a critical point at $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, thus our extreme value is at $(x_1, x_2) = \left(\frac{1}{2},0 \right)$

Comment: Hi Dan, what guarantee do we have that an extrema will exist along the boundary? How do we know that the extrema will not occur somewhere in the middle of that quadrant

Comment: Mostly because its a smooth function and the derivative didn't return any critical points in the domain of interest, usually the idea is that the domain isn't infinite, but you must always check the boundaries of the domain. This is the idea of the extreme value theorem, though this theorem doesn't usually apply to infinite domains